# Working With Stacks in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

After many hours of working on trying to debug this code myself I'm giving up an seeking help. I created a program that is designed to hold a "record", a struct, of my choice and show I know how to utilize/manipulate them in memory. In my code I made a car inventory that allows you to add, delete, and print out structs. My struct looks like the following:

```
struct car{
    char *make;
    char *model;
    int year;
    int mpg;
    int mileage;
    int cost;
};
```

I use a  menu system of number that allows the user to choose what to do with the struct. Anyways here's where I'm having the issue:

I can add two struct and print them all out just fine. However if I add more than two structs than I run into a seg fault. I've already tried to run GDB on it and I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a60a03 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=<optimized out>,     format=<optimized out>, 
ap=<optimized out>) at vfprintf.c:1661
1661    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
```

As for how I am taking in this data I have 6 scanf() functions that take in the 6 characteristics of the struct, store them to a temporary variable, malloc for each string, malloc a new `car struct` called `newCar`, and set each variable inside struct to its temporary variable. If it's the first car entry then `carInventory` is equal to `newCar`. When adding another car the same process occurs except a while loop moves along a new struct called `newCarInventory` and stores data from `carInventory` using `memcpy()`. Below is the actual code I'm using:

```
void addRecord(){

newCar = (struct car *) malloc(sizeof(struct car)); //Allocates memory for a car entry

int i;
int inventoryAmountTemp = inventoryAmount; //Grabs the global value and stores it to a local variable

//Local variables used to hold onto inputted values
char make[25];
char model[25];
int year;
int mpg;
int mileage;
int cost;

printf("\nMake: ");
scanf("%s", &make);
printf("\nModel: ");
scanf("%s", &model);
printf("\nYear: ");
scanf("%i", &year);
printf("\nMiles Per Gallon: ");
scanf("%i", &mpg);
printf("\nMileage: ");
scanf("%i", &mileage);
printf("\nCost: ");
scanf("%i", &cost);

newCar->make = (char *)malloc(strlen(make)+2); //Allocates memory for string
newCar->model = (char *)malloc(strlen(model)+2);
strcpy(newCar->make, make); //Coppies string into newCar
strcpy(newCar->model, model);
newCar->year = year;
newCar->mpg = mpg;
newCar->mileage = mileage;
newCar->cost = cost;

if(inventoryAmountTemp == 0){
    carInventory = newCar;
}
else{
    newCarInventory = (struct car *) malloc(inventoryAmountTemp * sizeof(struct car)); //Memory made for a new Car Inventory.
    headPtr = carInventory;
    headPtr2 = newCarInventory;
    tailPtr = newCar;

    i = 0;
    while(i <= inventoryAmountTemp){
        memcpy(&(newCarInventory->make), &(headPtr->make), sizeof(headPtr->make));
        memcpy(&(newCarInventory->model), &(headPtr->model), sizeof(headPtr->model)); 
        memcpy(&(newCarInventory->year), &(headPtr->year), sizeof(headPtr->year));
        memcpy(&(newCarInventory->mpg), &(headPtr->mpg), sizeof(headPtr->mpg));
        memcpy(&(newCarInventory->mileage), &(headPtr->mileage), sizeof(headPtr->mileage));
        memcpy(&(newCarInventory->cost), &(headPtr->cost), sizeof(headPtr->cost));

        i++;
        if(i < inventoryAmountTemp && i != inventoryAmountTemp){
            headPtr++;
            newCarInventory++;
        }
        else if(i == inventoryAmountTemp){
            headPtr = tailPtr;
            newCarInventory++;
        }

    }

    newCarInventory = headPtr2;
    carInventory = newCarInventory;
}

inventoryAmountTemp += 1;
accessTemp += 1;
access = accessTemp;
inventoryAmount = inventoryAmountTemp;
}
```

I know the issue resides from this function because I had fprintf() statements (that I took out in this code) that would test each step. The ones that would fail were the ones inside the while loop the as the loop went around the second time, of the third car entry.

Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Comment: Check your pointer handling carefully. A piece of paper, on which you draw boxes for `struct`s and arrows for pointers (and where they point to) while following your program step by step should make the mistake glaringly obvious. Perhaps starting the program under a debugger and getting a backtrace to determine where it goes awry might be helpful.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Consider using `strdup` or `asprintf`. Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the `gdb` debugger. Read documentation of all the functions you are using. You should use the result (count of scanned items) of `scanf`

Comment: We are *not* a "debug this broken piece of C for free" service, sorry.

Comment: By removing the question you prevent anyone else from learning from this question. The idea of stackoverflow is that everyone gains, not just that you get free personal service. Please restore the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct car{
    char *make;
    char *model;
    int year;
    int mpg;
    int mileage;
    int cost;
};
int inventoryAmount=0;
struct car* CarList=0;


char *copyString(char *str){
    char *buff=0;
    if(str){
        int l=strlen(str);
        buff=malloc(l+1);
        if(buff){
            for(int i=0;i<=l;i++)
                buff[i]=str[i];
        }

    }
    return buff;
}

/*_______________________________________________________
*/

void propmt(const char *msg,const char*fmt,void *output){
    printf("\n%s: ",msg);
    scanf(fmt,output);
    return;
}
/*_______________________________________________________
*/
void addRecord(void){


    struct car *newCar ;

    //Local variables used to hold onto inputted values
    char make[25];
    char model[25];
    int year;
    int mpg;
    int mileage;
    int cost;


    if(CarList){
        newCar=  realloc(CarList,sizeof(struct car)*(inventoryAmount+1)); 

    }else{
        newCar=  malloc(sizeof(struct car));

    }

    if(!newCar){
        printf("Failed to allocate new car\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    CarList=newCar;
    newCar=&newCar[inventoryAmount];
    inventoryAmount++;


    propmt("Make","%s", &make);
    propmt("Model","%s", &model);
    propmt("Year","%i", &year);
    propmt("Miles Per Gallon","%i", &mpg);
    propmt("Mileage","%i", &mileage);
    propmt("Cost","%i", &cost);


    newCar->make=copyString( make); //Coppies string into newCar
    newCar->model=copyString( model);
    newCar->year = year;
    newCar->mpg = mpg;
    newCar->mileage = mileage;
    newCar->cost = cost;

    return;
}

/*_______________________________________________________
*/

void listCars(void){
    int i;
    if(!inventoryAmount){
        printf("\nNo cars in inventory\n");
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<inventoryAmount;i++){
        printf("Make: %s\n"             ,CarList[i].make);
        printf("Model:%s\n"             ,CarList[i].model);
        printf("Year:%i\n"              ,CarList[i].year);
        printf("Miles Per Gallon:%i\n"  ,CarList[i].mpg);
        printf("Mileage:%i\n"           ,CarList[i].mileage);
        printf("Cost:%i\n"              ,CarList[i].cost);
        printf("======================================\n");
    }
    return;
}
void pause(void){
    printf("Press a key to continue");
    _getch();
    printf("\n");
}
int main(void){
    int q;
    for(;;){
        _clrscr();
        printf(
            "1 - List cars\n"
            "2 - Add new car\n"
            "0 - Exit program\n");
        scanf("%i",&q);
        switch(q){
            case 1:
                listCars();
                pause();
                break;
            case 2:
                addRecord();
                pause();
                break;
            case 0:
                return 0;
                break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

a good sample of using `malloc` and `realloc`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [backtrace](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/gdb-backtrace/) in gdb to see where the segmentation fault originates

Comment: Although this may be good advice, it's not really an answer, but to be fair, the question's not really a question.